# JS возвращает массив, который надо разобрать в java апплете

Tags: applet, javascript, java

В общем есть функция которая возвращает массив типа;

```
array[0] = somedata;
array[1] = somedata;
array[2] = somedata[];
.......
array[n] = somedata[];
```

Эти данные передаются в `java` апплет, вот как мне эти данные разобрать в самом апплете.
как скажем вытянуть данные из `array[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос что говорится - за гранью)), господин [[@Жека Петухов](/users/13921/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/13921/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2), не могли бы Вы выложить хоть пару строчек кода, а именно в каком виде эти данные передаются в `java` апплет.

А так, чтобы вытянуть отдельный элемент из массива, нет ничего сложного:

```
String[] array = new String[]{"samedata1","samedata2","samedata3"};
        String value = array[2];
```